# nodejs- req.body not parsing correctly for arrays and embedded object

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using nodejs(expressjs) as server. I have android app that sends json request to server. I have mongoose schema defined like this

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose'),
Schema=mongoose.Schema;

var actSchema= new Schema({
          actfees: {type: Number},
          actage: {
            from: {type: Number},
            to: {type: Number}
       },
       actbatches: [{ 
            days: [String], 
            starttime: {type: String},
            endtime: {type: String}
    }]
});
```

The incoming request looks like this

```
{ actId: '28',
  actage: '{from=3.0, to=40.0}',
  actbatches: '[{days=[Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri], endtime=17:00, starttime=16:00}]',
  actdescr: 'Learn 5 different style of swimming',
  actfees: '4000' 
}
```

See actage and actbatches parameters. They are treated as strings instead of array (in case of actbatches) or embedded objects(in case of age).

My app.js has following lines

```
var express = require('express')
, mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true)
, bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

//CLIENT CODE

BEAN Classes:

```
public class ActBean {

private String actfees;
private ActAgeBean actage;
private ArrayList<String> days;
getters & setters....
}

public class ActAgeBean {
  private int from;
  private int to;
//getters & setters...
}
```

Android Application Class:

```
private void Save(ActBean actbean)
{
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
    Map<String, Object> actMap = new Gson().fromJson(new Gson().toJson(actbean), type);
    post(url, actMap);
}
```

The post method:

```
public String post(String url, Map<String, Object> data) throws Exception {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = setParams(data);
    try {
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if(statusCode > 300){
            throw new Exception("Error executing POST request! Received error code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        //return new JSONObject(readInput(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        return readInput(response.getEntity().getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

setParams:

```
private List<NameValuePair> setParams(Map<String, Object> data){
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
    if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        Iterator<String> it = data.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String name = it.next();
            Object value = data.get(name);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value.toString()));
        }
    }
    return nameValuePairs;
}
```

Please suggest how can I make sure req.body correctly identifies array and embedded object.

Comment: `actage` and `actbatches` from your example are not correct json-objects and can not be parsed. Show the request code from the application side.

Comment: updated question with client app code. please check

Comment: What about `setParams` function?

Comment: updated original question with setParams